# ajax firing twice in an autocomplete search box with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

For my example I have a customer name form.

The user can start typing their name and a list of existing customers will appear.
They can then select the desired name and it will fill in all the name fields (first/middle/last)

The search/dropdown has to be triggered by typing in the FirstName field.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cc4V4/1/

HTML

```
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Start typing to search for a name" data-bind="value: FirstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" /></p>
<p><input type="text" data-bind="value: MiddleName" /></p>
<p><input type="text" data-bind="value: LastName" /></p>

<ul data-bind="foreach: Names, visible: ShowAjaxResults">
    <li data-bind="click: function() { selectName($data) }">
        <span data-bind="text: First"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Middle"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Last"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript/Knockout

```
var model = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Names = ko.observableArray([
            {First: "Joe", Middle: "Willikins", Last: "Bloggs"},
            {First: "Sam", Middle: "Silly", Last: "Smith"},
            {First: "Dog", Middle: "Zebra", Last: "Cat"}]);
    self.ShowAjaxResults = ko.observable(false);

    self.FirstName = ko.observable('').extend({ throttle: 500 });
    self.MiddleName = ko.observable('');
    self.LastName = ko.observable('');

    self.FirstName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       if(newValue.length > 2) {
            //ajax call to fill Names starting with newValue
            self.ShowAjaxResults(true);
            console.log('ajax call: ' + newValue);
       }

    });

    self.selectName = function(data) {
        self.FirstName(data.First);   
        self.MiddleName(data.Middle);
        self.LastName(data.Last);
        self.ShowAjaxResults(false);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model());
```

This works fine but the problem is of course, when selecting the name it will update FirstName, which then FirstName.subscribe goes off and does the ajax call again.

I've tried playing around with a few things but I'm stumped.

How can I stop the ajax firing again when selecting the desired name?

Perhaps there's a way to tell how the observable was updated? e.g only fire ajax through keypress updates

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, there are alot of auto-complete libraries out there, including this combo thats KO native.  https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox (I'm the author)

Comment: Yes that's useful but I find it a bit complicated. I'm trying to understand how to make one myself first. Are there any tutorials that would set me in the right direction of making a simple knockout combobox like yours?

Comment: Its not very complicated, check the live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/AWHhr/23/

Comment: getData is a function you need to implement, it takes a option argument. The option argument gives you page, pageSize, text and a callback. The callback expects a object that has data and total were data is a array of items and total is the total count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to `subscribe` to changes in `FirstName` but rather capture the `keyPress` event so you can show the user with name suggestions.

Try this:

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Start typing to search for a name"
       data-bind="value: FirstName, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: { keyup: AutoComplete }" />
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
var model = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.AutoComplete = function(data, event){
        var newValue = event.target.value;
        if(newValue.length > 2) {
            //ajax call to fill Names starting with newValue
            self.ShowAjaxResults(true);
            console.log('ajax call: ' + newValue);
       }
        return true;
    }    

    self.Names = ko.observableArray([
            {First: "Joe", Middle: "Willikins", Last: "Bloggs"},
            {First: "Sam", Middle: "Silly", Last: "Smith"},
            {First: "Dog", Middle: "Zebra", Last: "Cat"}]);
    self.ShowAjaxResults = ko.observable(false);

    self.FirstName = ko.observable('').extend({ throttle: 500 });
    self.MiddleName = ko.observable('');
    self.LastName = ko.observable('');

    self.selectName = function(data) {
        self.FirstName(data.First);   
        self.MiddleName(data.Middle);
        self.LastName(data.Last);
        self.ShowAjaxResults(false);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(model());
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cc4V4/20/

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just set up a boolean observable to flag when to fire the subscription:

```
self.fireSubscription = ko.observable(true);

self.FirstName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if(newValue.length > 2 && self.fireSubscription()) {
       //ajax call to fill Names starting with newValue
        self.ShowAjaxResults(true);
        console.log('ajax call: ' + newValue);
    }           
});

self.selectName = function(data) {
    self.fireSubscription(false);  // prevent the subscription firing
    self.FirstName(data.First);   
    self.MiddleName(data.Middle);
    self.LastName(data.Last);
    self.ShowAjaxResults(false);
    self.fireSubscription(true);   // enable the subscription 
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cc4V4/21/

Comment: This works when there is no throttle on FirstName, but having a throttle causes the original issue to happen again